# Adding a link to a section on the page, but the page is reloading when the link is clicked

Tags: html

I'm adding an anchor tag with a href that references a div on the same page.  The link should move the focus to the referenced div by the ID given to the href attribute.  Instead of moving the focus, the page is reloading.  When I inspect the link href in Chrome developer tools, part of the url is missing.  For instance, for the code below, if the full URL is https://awebsitename/somesection/someidentifier, the href in the debugger thinks the link should be https://awebsitename/#mainCont.

```
<a href="#mainCont">Jump to main content</a>

<div id="mainCont">Main Content Here</div>
```

The "Jump to main content" link on [this](https://html-css-js.com/?html=%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%20%20%3Chead%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EHTML%20CSS%20JS%3C/title%3E%0A%20%20%3C/head%3E%0A%20%20%3Cbody%20%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href=%22#mainContent%22%3EJump%20to%20main%20content%3C/a%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ch1%20i$*$d=%22welcome%22%20i$*$d=%22mainContent%22%3EHTML%20CSS%20JS%3C/h1%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20i$*$d=%22mainContent%22%3EWelcome%20to%20HTML-CSS-JS.com%3C/p%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3EOnline%20HTML,%20CSS%20and%20JavaScript%20editor%20%0A%09with%20instant%20preview.%3C/p%3E%0A%20%20%3C/body%3E%0A%3C/html%3E&css=/*%20CSS%20styles%20*/%0Ah1%20%7B%0A%20%20font-family:%20Impact,%20sans-serif;%0A%20%20color:%20#CE5937;%0A%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20&js=//%20JavaScript%0Adocument.getElementById(%27welcome%27).innerText%20%20=%20%0A%22%20Editors%22;%0A) jsfiddle works as it should.  My site will not work in the same way.

Comment: Can you provide a functional example? (Stack snippet, URL, Fiddle/Pen/etc.)

Comment: I've added a working fiddle.  I can't reproduce the issue there.

Comment: Do you have a URL where it isn't working as expected?

Comment: It's an internal website.

Answer (score 1):

it could be due to `href` of [base](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag:

```html
<base href="/">

<a href="#mainCont">Jump to main content</a>
<div id="mainCont">Main Content Here</div>
```

Comment: Ok, that looks like the likely cause.  Without changing the base href, how could I fix it?

Comment: if you cannot change `base`, as a variant, you can hardcode the absolute url: `<a href="/somesection/someidentifier#mainCont">`